# webview manual url redirection (manually set url's to show and skip)

Tags: android, webview, redirect

Im using a webview to display a website.
The page iam opening using loadurl method is the login page,
on successful login redirection occurs to a particular page .
I want to skip that page i.e dont want to show that page rather show the webpage after that

> eg If my webview starts with webpage **A**
>
> on login success it shows webpage **B**
>
> and then next page is webpage **C**
>
> *i want after Login success in page A it should go automatically to webpage C*

current code im using

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (Uri.parse(url)
                    .getHost()
                    .equals("https://www.test.com")) {
web.loadUrl("https://www.test1.com");

            }
            return false;
    }
```

so any tips/pointers as to how i do this?
thanks

Comment: @user3518278 Please do a google search before asking questions

Comment: @Vamshi ive updated the question withthe code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

You just need to do a string comparison from the site that you are in and the site that you want to go to.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thankyou hades
just one doubt

is it not possible to do a string comparison and then
if it matches the url i want to avoid i can do webview.loadUrl to the url i want to show?

Comment: ok
i tried to do it
but it didnt work
====================================================
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().trim().equals("https://www.test.com")) {
web.loadUrl("https://www.test1.com");
            }
            return false;
    }

Comment: @user3518278 you need to return true if your loading your own url